# Python help('modules') command throws WindowsError in IDLE (idle.pyw) but not command line prompt (python.exe)

Tags: python, windows-7, numpy, arcgis, python-idle

If I type the following at the python.exe command prompt...

```
>>>help('modules')
```

...I get a list of available modules as expected.

However when I type the same thing in the IDLE environment (idle.pyw), it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    help('modules')
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site.py", line 467, in __call__
  return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pydoc.py", line 1727, in __call__
  self.help(request)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pydoc.py", line 1766, in help
  elif request == 'modules': self.listmodules()
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pydoc.py", line 1887, in listmodules
  ModuleScanner().run(callback, onerror=onerror)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pydoc.py", line 1938, in run
  for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(onerror=onerror):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pkgutil.py", line 105, in walk_packages
  for importer, name, ispkg in iter_modules(path, prefix):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pkgutil.py", line 147, in iter_modules
  for name, ispkg in iter_importer_modules(i, prefix):
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\pkgutil.py", line 211, in iter_modules
  for fn in os.listdir(path):
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Msdtc/*.*'
```

Why does Windows say "Access is denied" to IDLE but not the command line?  I have tried using "Run as Administrator" on IDLE without success.  Do I need to reconfigure IDLE in some way?

For information:

My installation of Python 2.7.2 (32-bit version running on a Windows 7 64-bit machine) came bundled with ArcGIS 10.1, which uses Python as a scripting language and certain numerical operations (via Numpy).  Could this have something to do with the differing behaviour in the prompt and IDLE?

The root Python directory is: `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\`.

IDLE is installed at `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw`.

The Python command prompt is installed at: `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully ran `help('modules')` in both 2.7.8 and 3.4.2.  The response depends on sys.path.  It appears than ArcGIS adds C:/Windows/System32/Msdtc to the path, but you could check before running help.  In any case, accessing that folder cannot be done through Windows Explorer, even when running as an admin.  It requires special user action through a 'security tab'.  Since MS does not want me poking around there, I did not pursue getting access.  I don't know why the difference betweeon console and Idle.